# The string "Test '<3'" displays as "Test '<3>" in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, escaping

I'm having a strange problem where a user can enter the following text

> Test '<3'

and it outputs as

> Test '<3>

On the output I'm using white_list, and the value stored in the database is:

> 'testing ''<3'''

What could be causing the output to think it's a tag of some sort and trying to close it (which is what it looks like to me).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters in Ruby such as &, < and @ can sometimes be misinterpreted. Try using the "h" method in .rhtml pages.

```
<strong><%= h("This is a quick Test'<3'.") %></strong>
```

Will output:

```
<strong>This is a quick Test'&lt;3'.</strong>
```

So your browser will interpret it as:

**This is a quick Test'<3'.**

(I'm still relatively new to Ruby so I'm open to correction!)

Comment: `h` is an alias for the `html_escape` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#M000337

Comment: I was actually trying to escape it with h but I was on the wrong view, doh!  Swapping it from white_list string to h string worked.  Thanks for keeping me on my toes.